# Is there a handy alternative to change volume balance in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

I need to change volume balance every now and then as my headphones have the right ear too silent (while still very good in all the other criteria) while the built-in speakers are Ok. Unfortunately balance adjustment is hidden so deep in Windows 7 that it annoys me a lot to go there every time (it was much better in XP). Is there an alternative way to change it? Like a handy app just for this, a console/powershell command or a scripting way? I only need to switch between two states: normal and one biased.

UPDATE: Though I have accepted an answer, I am still looking for better alternatives as the app suggested is, as I have said, too unstable.

Comment: RE: "my headphones have the right ear too silent..." Does this happen only when the headphones are connected to the PC? Do the headphones happen to have an inline microphone?

Comment: if you know Java or just a little bit of programming you can do something like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume)

Comment: No mic, @PFitz, it's Creative EP-630, the problem is with a pocket player too and there is no problem with another headset (that one having a mic actually) with the same PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleSndVol is a small Windows plugin that will add a tray icon with added functionality, including balance control. It will also allow you to map balance control to a HotKey. Link below.

http://winaero.com/download.php?view.12

Comment: Looks great but too buggy - it slides the volume down when I change the balance and fails with an unhanded division by zero exception when I try to slide the volume up from 0 or even just start it when the volume is set to 0.

Comment: In that case, maybe there's a Windows Desktop Gadget that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I've found a great free app that allows to to control sound settings with mouse gestures and hot keys. I set it up to change L/R balance percent with a hot keys. It also has a dozens cool features to work with sound on Windows - [Volume2: blog](https://irzyxa.wordpress.com/) or [Volume2: Official site](http://volumesqr.at.ua/publ/)

[image]

P.S.: please [donate](http://volumesqr.at.ua/index/donate/0-8) author if you liked the software

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't remember the desired Balance after you lower and then raise the volume... which was the whole reason I needed something like this.