# WMI script to adjust Speakers' Balance (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, wmi, volume-mixer

I would like to create a script that configures the Balance on my Speakers-- specifically I would like to call WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) from a VBScript if possible. Is this adjustment possible via WMI or similar? What are the relevant commands?

**Background:**

Unfortunately one of the speakers is not working well and it sounds awful unless I limit it to 12% or lower. I can adjust it manually in the control panel of Sound : Playback -> Levels (see image). However, whenever I lower the volume then raise it again, the balance is out of whack. It is a real pain to go back into the settings each time.

**Note:**

If there is not any way to do this via WMI or similar scripts, then I will probably automate it using AutoIt, because I do not wish to download a third-party software from an untrustworthy source. (That means I cannot use the solutions presented in this similar question: [Is there a handy alternative to change volume balance in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/693462/is-there-a-handy-alternative-to-change-volume-balance-in-windows-7)). I will consider a software solution an acceptable answer if it is FOSS, something from Microsoft or other well-known source (and free/inexpensive).

[image]